# JPA Query Count

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

as you see i have this method that i want count passwords that have have 8 and more.
But its showing **Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT COUNT(p) from Perdoruesi p where DATALENGTH(p.password) > 8].**

```
public long securityPasswordCheckChart() throws PerdoruesiException{
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p) from Perdoruesi p where DATALENGTH(p.password) > 8");
            try{
                return (long)query.getSingleResult();
            }catch(NoResultException e){
                throw new PerdoruesiException("ur");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATALENGTH is from SQLServer isn't available in MySQL, to get the length of a string in MySQL use CHAR_LENGTH or LENGTH

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p) from Perdoruesi p where CHAR_LENGTH(p.password) > 8");
```